# How to config SSH for gitlab?

Tags: ssh, git-clone

In my experience of Github, I tought that I need to clone a repository with my user like `user@gitlabhost.com`. But when I try this, then it does not recognize my password from gitlab. Only cloning with gitlab user does work.

Can anybody please help me??? - How do I have to configure gitlab access right?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you followed Installation Instructions of gitlab, then you must have installed it on an linux box under the user named `git`. Typically in a folder like this

```
/home/git/gitlab
```

Hence you should use `git@gitlabhost.com`

I am not sure what you mean by "configuring SSH". But since each user is expected to use her own keypair, there should be no problem in accessing gitlab managed repo's using normal git commands. Both the following should work

```
git clone ssh://git@gitlabhost.com/group/repo.git
git clone git@gitlabhost.com:group/repo.git
```

Each user must have set their own git identity (on their local machines) using

```
git config --global user.name "elitmus"
git config --global user.email "abc@gmail.com"
```

so that git can uniquely identify each user.

Comment: Hi. How can I use a different username when cloning from gitlabs using ssh?

Comment: how can I see which username I am using because I do not find it in a home directory and Gitlab give me git@host.com

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, I had to connect to the gitlab server, as the git user, and modify the `authenticated_keys` file, as it was filled with a bunch of random `#`'s. after clearing that, I added my SSH key in the GitLab GUI and was able to clone and push normally.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't understand what could make that happen.  Thanks for posting though, that was a lifesaver.

Answer (score 1):

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

**Generating a new SSH key and adding it to GitLab or github or any ssh-agent**

for more information
https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/about-ssh