# Gitlab connection to Android studio

Tags: git, android-studio

So I have a gitlab repo and I have already cloned it via source tree in my folder , I have now imported it to Android studio and I want to now connect it. It uses an SSH key for the url, But android studio says "Please enter password for user ..." and I dont know what password this is and cant read from remote repo. Please help.

I am able to connect to my github repos but the problem is my gitlab which is the only one I am connecting with an ssh key

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use a HTTP connection for GitLab like you would use with GitHub?

Comment: well dont know everyone one working on the project is using the ssh key and thats what they used to clone it. I dont know the difference.

Comment: In my experience it is a better, more simple experience. But as it seems this is a potential duplicate of  these [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837103/gitlab-cant-clone-repository-even-though-ssh-works) or this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18472473/how-to-config-ssh-for-gitlab)